# Wordpress Editor converts ampersand to &#038;

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, encoding, editor

when I am setting the src of an iframe dynamically with the following javascript in Wordpress:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('iframe').attr('src', 'http://someurl.com/?originid=PORTAL&amp;tijdsblokstart=1700&amp;datum=2014-05-19'); 
});
```

The last 2 parameters are not picked up. I know it has someting to do with the encoding of the ampersand, but I tried everything...I'm lost now.

```
 - &
 - &amp;
 - &#038;
 - creating the whole iframe in jQuery
```

The src has to be set dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're URL encoding all but the 1st value?  Try `http://someurl.com/?originid=PORTAL&tijdsblokstart=1700&datum=2014-05-19`

Comment: Can you get at the logs on the target server? To see exactly what URL it is receiving.

Comment: what if you don't encode url?

Comment: Same result, if I use just & it gets encoded to &#038;

Comment: well i tried on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tzAR5/ but didn't find anything wrong

Comment: Stupid of me sorry, but now I see the WP-editor is messing things up. First time using WP...

Comment: If you can't fix this or you have a solution, could you change your question to be more oriented around the WordPress editor and tag it so that other users have a chance of benefiting from this? I did a search and there appears to be no other questions addressing this so I think you will be ok and it won't be a duplicate.

Comment: To clarify - if you do find a solution, could you change the question and also post it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by creating a function in an external js-file that generates the url for me. So avoid using the ampersand in the Wordpress editor. I would love to hear if someone comes up with a better solution.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Could you provide a non-domain-specific example? Would make your answer better. Thanks =]

Answer (score 1):

If your problem occurs in post content, there is no universal solution.

Indeed, the `&` is replaced by `&#038;` by the `wptexturize` function from `wp-includes\formatting.php`:

```
// Replace each & with &#038; unless it already looks like an entity.

$curl = preg_replace( '/&(?!#(?:\d+|x[a-f0-9]+);|[a-z1-4]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;', $curl );
```

It's hooked to the `the_content` filter in file `wp-includes\default-filters.php` :

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wptexturize' );
```

The problem is that you can remove this filter but you will loose a lot of formating done by this huge `wptexturize` function.

***One solution for op*** would be to find a way to remove the ampersand from the code. To do this, you can use `jQuery.param` to generate the querystring part of the url:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('iframe').attr('src', 'http://someurl.com/?' + jQuery.param({originid: 'PORTAL', tijdsblokstart: 1700, datum: '2014-05-19'})); 
});
```

A really ***dirty*** solution would be:

1. to register a filter to execute before the `wptexturize` one using priority 9 (by default, priority is 10) so it change your ampersand to something really unique that the `wptexturize` function will not alter
2. to register a filter to execute after the `wptexturize` one using priority 11 that changes back your ampersand subtitute to a real ampersand

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that worked for me:

```
char = '&amp;';
char = char.replace('amp;', '');
console.log(char);
```